# get media:description and media:content url from xml

Tags: php, xml

I have `XML` data in which some item tag have **media: content** tag some have not. How can I check that content exists in that `XML` and also, how can I get description under **media: content** tag? 
Here is `XML` data:

```
<rss xmlns:content="" xmlns:wfw="" xmlns:dc="" xmlns:atom="" xmlns:sy="" xmlns:slash="" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>Title1</title>
            <link>Link</link>
            <pubDate>Date</pubDate>
            <content:encoded>
                <![CDATA[ This is description 1 ]]>
                <![CDATA[ This is description 2 ]]>
            </content:encoded>
            <media:content url="URL" type="image/jpeg">
                <media:description>
                    <![CDATA[ Text ]]>
                </media:description>
            </media:content>
        </item>

        <item> -- this item tag does not have media: content
            <title>Title2</title>
            <link>Link2</link>
            <pubDate>Date2</pubDate>
            <content:encoded>
                <![CDATA[ This is description 3 ]]>
                <![CDATA[ This is description 4 ]]>
            </content:encoded>
        </item>

        <item>
            <title>Title3</title>
            <link>Link3</link>
            <pubDate>Date3</pubDate>
            <content:encoded>
                <![CDATA[ This is description 5 ]]>
                <![CDATA[ This is description 6 ]]>
            </content:encoded>
            <media:content url="UR1L" type="image/jpeg">
                <media:description>
                    <![CDATA[ Text 2 ]]>
                </media:description>
            </media:content>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

What I tried is:

```
<?php
function feeds() 
{
    $url = "http://localhost/xmldata/xmld.xml"; // xmld.xml contains above data
    $feeds = file_get_contents($url);
    $rss = simplexml_load_string($feeds);
    foreach($rss->channel->item as $entry) {
         if($entry->children('media', true)->content->attributes()) {
                $md = $entry->children('media', true)->content->attributes();
                print_r("$md->url");
            }
    }
}
?>
```

It is returning me error like below:

> Node no longer exists

Even I don't have any idea to get **media:description** which is in **media:content** tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if the 'media:content' property is set on the [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

I think it would help if you change these lines:

```
foreach($rss->channel->item as $entry) {
    if($entry->children('media', true)->content->attributes()) {
        $md = $entry->children('media', true)->content->attributes();
        print_r("$md->url");
    }
}
```

To these lines:

```
$rss = @simplexml_load_string($feeds);
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $entry) {
    if (isset($entry->{'media:content'})) {
        $url = (string)$entry->{'media:content'}->attributes()->url;
        $description = (string)$entry->{'media:content'}->{'media:description'};
        echo "$url<br>";
        echo "$description<br>";
    }
}
```

Will result in:

> URL
>
> Text
>
> UR1L
>
> Text 2

Comment: this is not working .. it is not displaying the url and description

Comment: Can you test it if you use this to load the rss: `$rss = @simplexml_load_string($feeds);`
Like in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/YPLEd)

Comment: Do you see the expected result when you load http://localhost/xmldata/xmld.xml in your browser?
Can you check your feed in [this validator](https://validator.w3.org/feed/#validate_by_input)?
Are there any log files you can check for error messages? What happens when you for example run the code from the [demo](https://3v4l.org/YPLEd) on your localhost. Does that display any results?

Answer (score 2):

It is working for me .

```
$namespaces = $entry->getNamespaces(true);   

$media_url =    trim((string)$entry->children($namespaces['media'])->content->attributes()->url);
```